# Getting human readable info about CPU

Tags: java, android, human-readable

I am trying to get info about smartphone's CPU. 
I can get that from displaying /proc/cpuinfo file. However its output is poor and unreadable.
I would like to have output like from "lscpu" command but when I execute command "lscpu" from my app I have no permissions to do that (however I can do that from Termux console on my phone and output is readable).
Do you have any ideas how to get human readable?

Here is code to view /proc/cpuinfo file:

```
static class CMDExecute {
    synchronized String run(String[] cmd)
            throws IOException {
        String result = "";

        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = builder.start();
            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
            byte[] re = new byte[1024];
            while (in.read(re) != -1) {
                System.out.println(new String(re));
                result = result + new String(re);
            }
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

private static StringBuffer buffer;

public static void fetch_cpu_info() {
    String result = null;
    CMDExecute cmdexe = new CMDExecute();
    try {
        String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
        result = cmdexe.run(args);
        System.out.println("RESULT\n" + result);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and its output:

I/System.out: 
RESULT

```
processor   : 0
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
processor   : 1
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
processor   : 2
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
processor   : 3
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

As you can see it's very poor output. When I try to perform "lscpu" command from my code, changing only one line:

```
        String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
```

to

```
        String[] args = {"lscpu"};
```

I am getting error:

**W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lscpu": error=13, Permission denied**

However, I have application Termux on my phone. It's shell console and I don't know why but I can perform "lscpu" in this console (I cannot from app code). Check this out:

[lscpuoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGI7b.jpg)

I would like to get that output into my app. Do you have any ideas how to get that nice human readable output about CPU info?

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I was able to solve the problem for the most part. Focusing on /proc/cpuinfo only was not good idea.
Instead, I managed to get interesting hardware info like that:

Get smartphone manufacturer and model. In my case the output is: "samsung SM-J730F":

```
    String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
```

This command shows number of CPU cores:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

From this file you can get your CPU frequency. Remember to use .trim() because this file may contain whitespace character like it was in my case and I had problem to convert result to float for further operations:

```
   ("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq").trim()
```

File containing number of online CPUs:

```
   /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
```

File containing number of offline CPUs. If all CPUs are online, this file seems to be empty but it may contain whitespace char:

```
  ("/sys/devices/system/cpu/offline").trim()
```

Command to get architecture:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

With all of this I created nice, human readable output. I guess this topic can be closed.
Best Regards!